# Wordpress page password protection is not working. Page still visible

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

First time trying to use the password protected visibility option on a Wordpress page, and it seems to do nothing. After adding a password, if I view the page it never asks for a password. Different browsers, clearing out all temporary files, logging out of wordpress admin, nothing makes a difference. Even logged into a remote computer that had never been to the site or admin and opened the page without any prompt for a password. Has anyone else ran into this issue? My Google skills are failing me.

Comment: It would help if we knew which version of WordPress you're running.  Maybe a reference to your site and the 'protected' page so we can see it in action, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ended up discovering that the template needed the content() function in it for the password prompt to appear. For those that are in my situation and need to password protect content or PHP scripts in a whole template, this works http://wordpress.org/support/topic/346373

Comment: You are right - I was manipulating the post_content directly - and so I ended up needing to use [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378099/2100636) in combination with this knowledge dropped in this one!

Answer (score 6):

Seems like the theme has to support this functionality. I found out that you have to use something like this to make it work

```
<?php 
    if (post_password_required()) { 
        echo get_the_password_form();
    } else {
        echo "<p>Protected content</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Excellent answer for being able to manually control when this happens without having to rely on `get_the_content()` or `the_content()`